# meaning of the word "go" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from [Crash Course US history](https://youtu.be/F7flSW1PGsA). It is at 8 minute and 10 second.

> So with its stirring anti-tariff, anti-monopoly, do not pass **go**, do not collect 200 dollars stance, New Freedom won out.

Actually I cannot get the whole sentence, so could you please explain it to me?

Comment: It’s a reference to a famous board game in the west: Monopoly. Every time you complete a cycle in a game, your marker passes over a square named “Go”, and you’re given $200 (game money) for the next round. Sometimes, if you get a bad dice roll, you can be sent to jail, directly, and the rules for that say “just put your marker in jail immediately; or doesn’t count if you have to pass the “Go” square on the way or not; you won’t get your $200. Just go right to jail”.

Comment: One would write it as: **do not pass "Go"**. –

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a reference to the board game "Monopoly".

In that game, when a player passes the square "Go" they automatically collect $200 from the bank (£200 in the UK version I used to play).

There is a card which says "Go directly to Jail. Do not pass Go. Do not collect £200".

This phrase ("Do not pass Go, do not collect 200 dollars") has entered the language.

Here there is a play on words because they are talking about an anti-monopoly stance. I'm not certain what they mean, but I think the idea is that New Freedom regard "collecting $200" as representing getting something for nothing, are opposed to this.